# Field label language in Validation codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-4

How I can display field name from my language file in validation message (Codeigniter 4)?
My language file in **app/Languages/ar/App.php**

I did this in **Config/Validation.php**

```
public $updateSettings = [
  'site_name' => ['label' => 'App.site_name', 'rules' => 'required'],
];
```

But still label displays as (site_name) and not the content of my language file.